# How to specify a service override further down the dependency graph in Castle Windsor?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Here is a simplification of my scenario.

I have some interfaces `IFoo`, `IBar`, and `IBaz` with their implementations `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz`.

`Foo` depends on `IBar` and `Bar` depends on `IBaz`, so the dependency graph looks like this:

```
   Foo 
    |
   Bar
    |
   Baz
```

My Windsor config looks like this, and everything works as expected:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>());
container.Register(Component.For<IBar>().ImplementedBy<Bar>());
container.Register(Component.For<IBaz>().ImplementedBy<Baz>());
```

Now I need to introduce a new `SpecialBaz`, and I want to use it instead of the old `Baz` when my dependency graph begins with a `Foo`.  The rest of the app will continue to the the old `Baz`:

```
      Foo           SomethingElse
       |                  |
      Bar                Bar
       |                  |
   SpecialBaz            Baz
```

I have tried naming the `SpecialBaz` with the `ServiceOverride` api:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IBaz>().ImplementedBy<Baz>().IsDefault());
container.Register(Component.For<IBaz>().Named("special baz").ImplementedBy<SpecialBaz>());

container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>()
                            .ImplementedBy<Foo>()
                            .DependsOn(ServiceOverride.ForKey<IBaz>().Eq("special baz")));
```

And specifying the dependency:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IBaz>().ImplementedBy<Baz>().IsDefault());
container.Register(Component.For<IBaz>().ImplementedBy<SpecialBaz>());

container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>()
                            .ImplementedBy<Foo>()
                            .DependsOn(Component.For<IBaz>().ImplementedBy<SpecialBaz>()));
```

But neither approach worked.

Is this possible in Castle Windsor, and how do I wire it up?

Comment: Please try removing `IsDefault()` on the first registration of `IBaz`.

Comment: Are Foo and SomethingElse implementations of IFoo?

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt that didn't work I'm afraid.  Also don't forget that `Baz` is the default implementation of `IBaz` in this case and everyone else should an instance of it.  It's when the dependency graph starts with a `Foo` that the `SpecialBaz` should be used instead.

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov no, the `SomethingElse` is a different class which also depends on the `IBar -> IBaz` dependency graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **short** answer is **yes** - Castle Windsor can. Every DI container can. I will offer you a rule to remember by which you can resolve most of your dependency problems.

The **long** answer.

The rule : **Every point of indirection requires a layer of abstraction**. Keep this rule in mind when you try to build dependency resolutions in apps. And there are **two kinds of indirections** as far as I know - **static and dynamic.**

You need to change the graph at **one point** and **only once** (**indirections**) but somehow you need to traverse the dependecies graph at runtime to see if your Baz is requested for Foo or not. So you need a factory  of some kind(**the abstraction thingie**).

You have **two options** depending on the answer of one question:

**Is my change dependent on static or dynamic conditions?**

For example - If you depend on incoming user data or environment data - you are in the dynamic case in which you will need yo use [Dynamic Parameters](http://kozmic.net/2009/12/10/castle-windsor-new-feature-ndash-dynamic-parameters-from-registration-site/)  or something else capable.

In your case your dependency is static.

> and I want to use it instead of the old Baz when my dependency graph begins with a Foo.

The condition for special Baz never changes once the beginning of the graph is Foo.

You can achieve this with Factory method or Typed Factory Componend Selector. I provide you an example with Factory Method :

```
using System;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer();
            container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>());
            container.Register(Component.For<ISomethingElse>().ImplementedBy<SomethingElse>());

            container.Register(Component.For<IBar>().ImplementedBy<Bar>().LifeStyle.Transient);

            container.Register
            (
                Component
                .For<IBaz>()
                .UsingFactoryMethod
                (
                    (k, c) =>
                    {
                        IBaz resolved = null;
                        var requestingType = c.Handler.ComponentModel.Implementation;
                        if (requestingType == typeof(Foo))
                        {
                            resolved = new Baz();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            resolved = new BazSpecial();
                        }

                        return resolved;
                    }
                ).LifeStyle.Transient
            );

            var f = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
            var se = container.Resolve<ISomethingElse>();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    internal interface IBar
    {
    }

    internal interface IBaz
    {
    }

    internal interface IFoo
    {
    }

    interface ISomethingElse
    {

    }


    internal class Bar : IBar
    {
        private readonly IBaz baz;

        public Bar(IBaz baz)
        {
            this.baz = baz;
        }

    }

    internal class Baz : IBaz
    {
    }

    internal class BazSpecial : IBaz
    {
    }

    internal class Foo : IFoo
    {
        private readonly IBar bar;

        public Foo(IBar bar)
        {
            this.bar = bar;
        }
    }

    internal class SomethingElse : ISomethingElse
    {
        private readonly IBar bar;

        public SomethingElse(IBar bar)
        {


         this.bar = bar;
        }
    }
}}
```